# Does SDL Tridion Sites 9 accept DD4T XML model?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t, dd4t-2, sites-9

Currently we have a .NET webapplication which still uses DD4T 1.31. The CMS version is currently SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. We want to update to SDL Tridion Sites 9. Is it possible to update DD4T but stay on the 'old' XML dataformat?

Of course we have also plannend to update the dataformat but I am investigating what all possible scenarios are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no provider to make DD4T version 1 work with Tridion 9. You have 2 choices:

1. Upgrade to DD4T 2.
2. Create your own Tridion 9 provider.

If you go for option 2, you must also update the ProviderAssemblyNames.cs class in the DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts assembly, and add your custom provider name there.

Comment: Before I accept the answer, can I just update to DD4T 2.0, without using the JSON datamodel (so keep using the old XML model).

Comment: It's possible, but there are some caveats. I suggest you check out this blog by Pankaj Gaur: https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/upgrade-to-dd4t-2-0-overview/.

Comment: Thank you, Quirijn. Perfect answers on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Please read more about here [DD4T Supports SDL Tridion Sites 9](http://blog.trivident.com/dd4t-supports-sdl-tridion-sites-9/), In your case, you might need to upgrade your DD4T version to the latest one both web app as well CME DD4T templates.

**Note:**

It's supported only microservices-based implementation when upgrading to Sites 9

I hope it helps.